# Установка Nuget - пакетов в VS для проекта WPF NetCore 3.1

Tags: wpf, .net-core, nuget, .net-4.8

1. Проект Wpf Net4.8.
   --- устанавливаю пакеты в VS - для Решения - из nuget.org - стандартным образом - без ошибок.
   --- При этом - пакет packages - устанавливается в папку с Решением - все ссылки установленных dll - на packages - в Решении.
2. Проект Wpf Core3.1.
   --- Также как в п.1 - устанавливаю пакеты - для Решения - без ошибок.
   --- При этом пакета packages (в проекте с Решением) - нет.
   --- Ссылки установленных пакетов - на packages - расположенной по пути - C:\Users\name.packages...
3. Мне нужно переделать старый проект wpf Net4.8 для wpf NetCore 3.1 --- Cпецифика проекта требует расположения packages в папке с Решениеми.
4. Подскажите, пожалуйста, - как для проекта wpf Core3.1 - создать packages (и ссылки на него)- в папке с Решением, как и для старого проекта ?

Answer (score 0):

Папку с пакетами можно указать с помощью `nuget.config`, создайте его командой в проекте: `dotnet new nuget` и добавьте туда:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- остальная часть файла -->
  <config>
    <!-- в value указываете путь -->
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="./packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

После этого пакеты должны будут ставиться в папку `packages` внутри проекта.